# xpath: Unable to locate Select dropdown

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the following exceptions,

> invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath
>   expression //select[@name='countryList because of the following error:
>   SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
>   '//select[@name='countryList' is not a valid XPath expression.

Here is my html code,

```
<form method="post" action="/eClaims/app" name="itemEditForm" id="itemEditForm" class="itemEditForm" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="formids" value="TextField,wdd">
<input type="hidden" name="component" value="ClaimItemDetail.itemEditForm">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="ClaimItemPage">
<input type="hidden" name="service" value="direct">
<input type="hidden" name="session" value="T">
<input type="hidden" name="If_87" value="T">
<input type="hidden" name="For_3" value="ecfqwcqw">

</div>
    <input type="text" name="TextField" value="" id="requestKeyItemId" style="visibility: hidden">
    <!-- START ORDERED Item detail table  -->   
        <div name="mainClaimItemDetailDiv">
            <table width="100%" bgcolor="#cccccc">

            </table>            
            <!-- show item information section START -->
            <table width="100%" bgcolor="#cccccc">
                <tbody><tr bgcolor="silver">
                    <th>
                        HP Item Ref.
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        Estimated Value
                        (
                        AUD
                        )<br>
                    </th>

                        <th>
                            Country of Origin
                        </th>                                       
                        <th>
                            Serial #
                        </th>                   
                    <th>
                        Estimated Value($)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input type="text" name="clmid" value="" id="clmid" style="visibility: hidden;">
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr width="100%" bgcolor="#cccccc">
                    <td align="center">
                        56730270
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        252.79
                    </td>                   
                        <td align="center">

                                <!--<span jwcid="countryList_1" onchange="javascript:checkIfDropdownValueNull(this);" ></span> -->
                                <select name="countryList_1" id="countryList_1" style="width:50px;">
<option value="">--please select--</option>
<option value="AF">AF</option>

<option value="ZW">ZW</option>
</select>
                        </td>


                        <td align="center">

                                <input type="text" name="serialNo_2" value="5CD6340S04" id="serialNo_2" maxl="10" onfocus="javascript:onProductFocus(this);" size="10" onblur="javascript:onItemDataChange(this,10)">                           
                        </td>

                    <td align="center">
                        187.06
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="fetchitemBtn" class="fetchitemBtn" style="visibility: hidden;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>    
</form>
```

So far i have used the following locators,

```
//select[contains(@id,'countryList_1')]

//select[@id,'countryList_1']

//**[@id="itemEditForm"]/div[@name='mainClaimItemDetailDiv']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]

//**[@id="itemEditForm"]/div[@name='mainClaimItemDetailDiv']/following::select[@id='countryList_1']
```

Although, the last xpath is not locating any element.
I have used many more but to no avail.

please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `//select[@id='countryList_1']` will find a dropdown with id = 'countryList_1'. I've checked it on your HTML and it's working fine. Check for typos.

Comment: I think there is syntax mistake in your xpath

Comment: is your problem is solved?

Comment: Yes, used the following xpath :

Comment: //*[@id="itemEditForm"]/div[@name='mainClaimItemDetailDiv']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]/select

Answer (score 0):

Use following xpath in your code it is working fine

You can follow any of these xpaths:

```
//select[@id='countryList_1']

//select[@name='countryList_1']

//select[@id='countryList_1'][@name='countryList_1']

//select[contains(@name,'countryList_1')]
```

In your error log

> "The string '//select[@name='countryList' is not a valid XPath
>   expression."

that means your xpath is not correct, you have some syntax error in xpath

Answer (score 0):

your xpath is missing an ']'. use correct xpath as shown below

```
//select[@name='countryList']
```